# Change country label mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, gis, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Can I change the label of a country using Mapbox Gl Js?

When I use mapbox I want to change the label of an country like this

**example: united state -> usa**

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/customize-label-text/) from Mapbox's documentation shows how to customize the label text for a single label. So, you could apply the same logic to the "United States" label to have it read "USA" in your map style. You can then use this custom map style in your GL JS application as shown in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-id/). The "hosted style ID" that the example calls for can be found through the process documented [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/overview/publish-your-style/).